# Sequence in hilbert space, mutually orthogonal vectors

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $y_1,y_2,\cdots$ be a sequence in a Hilbert space. Let $V_n$ be the linear span of $\{y_1,\cdots,y_n\}$. Assume that $||y_{n+1}||\leq ||y-y_{n+1}||$ for all $y\in V_n$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$. Show that $\left<y_i,y_j\right>=0$ for $i\neq j$.

I was trying as follows. Set $V_2'$ to be span of $\{y_2,y_3,\cdots\}$ this being finite dimensional is a closed subspace of $H$. So, we have $H=V_2'\oplus V_2'^{\perp}$..

I wanted to proceed like this but could not go too far.

Please give only hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint is to expand the inequality you have (for which you'll have to square), and to remember that $V_n$ is a vector space.

Assuming the space is real, if you expand from $\|y_{n+1}\|\leq\|y-y_{n+1}\|$ you get
$$\tag{1}
\langle y,y_{n+1}\rangle\leq \frac12\|y\|^2,\ \ y\in V_n.
$$
Now, if we take $y=y_k$ for some $k\leq n$, 
$$
\langle y_k,y_{n+1}\rangle\leq \frac12\|y_k\|^2.
$$
But $-y_k\in V_n$, so from $(1)$ we get 
$$
-\langle y_k,y_{n+1}\rangle\leq \frac12\|y_k\|^2.
$$
It follows that
$$
|\langle y_k,y_{n+1}\rangle|\leq \frac12\|y_k\|^2.
$$
And $t y_k\in V_n$ for all $t>0$ (in particular), so 
$$
\langle y_k,y_{n+1}\rangle\leq \frac t{2}\|y_k\|^2, \ \ t>0. 
$$
Thus
$$
\langle y_k,y_{n+1}\rangle=0.
$$

Comment: Expanding the inequality gives me $\left<y,y\right>\geq 2\left<y,y_{n+1}\right>$... could not go beyond this..

Comment: So much for "hints only" ;). Please see the edit.

Comment: I feel bad that i could not think of this idea. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. We all learn ideas from what we see others do.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: How do you get the inequality $<y_k , y_{n+1}> \leq \frac{1}{2t} ||y_k||^2  ? $ I guess it should be $<y_k , y_{n+1}> \leq \frac{t}{2} ||y_k||^2.$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks.